# Does unpublish in Child Publication also applies to Dynamic Component Presentations?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, dynamic-publishing

I am trying to convert a bunch Dynamic Component Templates (for the reasons very well described here: [Dynamic vs. Static Component Templates](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dcp-etiquette-why-would-you-make-a-component-template-dynamic)), and first I need to unpublish all the wrongly-published DCPs. There are a few CTs that are used in children publications (Mobile Web for example) and I am unpublishing it with the "Unpublish in Child Publications" within the Advanced Tab in the Publishing dialog, checked.

However the DCPs are not being unpublished from the children publications.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't they unpbulish too?

**Note:** all children publications use the same publication target with the same target types.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on whether you have the same Target Types for the child publication or not. 
If the Target Types are different in the child publications, then the one that you are selecting for unpublish in your current publication, it will not unpublish from the child publication. As long as the Target Types are same, it should work.

Comment: I checked and they both use the same publication target, with the same target type.

Comment: Does the user with which you are trying unpublish has permission on the child publication target as well? Also, can you expand show items to publish and verify you see all you expect?